# Error en formato de fecha sql server 2012

Tags: sql

Tengo una aplicación cuya información esta almacenada en una base de datos en sql server pero tengo el siguiente inconveniente:

Al realizar una consulta con el siguiente script directamente desde el motor de sql server me devuelve registros:

```
SELECT * FROM PR_11 WHERE FECHA_DESDE > '28/07/2014' AND CODIGO='4891';
```

El campo `FECHA_DESDE` es de tipo `DATETIME`.

Pero, si la misma consulta la realizo desde el editor de sql, me devuelve el siguiente error, el cuál adjunto en la siguiente imagen.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A qué se puede deber eso.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para que en base a tu formato '28/07/2014' y convirtiendo este valor a datetime, realice la comparación.

Answer (score 5):

Usa el método **[CONVERT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)**

```
CONVERT(datetime, @TU_VALOR , 103)
```

En tu caso podrías obtener el valor `DateTime` con formato `dd/mm/yyyy` en base al string `'28/07/2014'`

```
DECLARE @miFecha char(10) = '28/07/2014'
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(@miFecha,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@miFecha,4,2)+'/'+RIGHT(@miFecha,4),103)
```

Resultado:   `2014-07-28 00:00:00.000`

En base a esto tu script quedaría como:

```
DECLARE @miFecha char(10) = '28/07/2014'
SELECT * FROM PR_11 WHERE FECHA_DESDE > CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(@miFecha,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@miFecha,4,2)+'/'+RIGHT(@miFecha,4),103) AND CODIGO='4891';
```

El formato a usar sería el `103` (`dd/mm/yyyy`) como se especifica en
**[Date and Time Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)**

Answer (score 3):

El problema se produce porque la conversión de una cadena de texto en una fecha depende de la configuración del idioma de la conexión.

Para evitar este problema puedes hacer dos cosas:

1. Utilizar la función `CONVERT()` que te indica @Elenasys en su respuesta
2. Utilizar un literal de fecha, es decir, escribir la fecha en formato `'YYYYMMDD'` o `'YYYY-MM-DD'`

Aplicando esto último, tu consulta quedaría:

```
SELECT * FROM PR_11 WHERE FECHA_DESDE > '20140728' AND CODIGO='4891';
```

Este artículo ["Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries"](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx) es muy interesante y explica esta problemática

Personalmente:

- Cuando estoy lanzando consultas para hacer pruebas o extraer ciertos datos uso los **literales** porque es mas cómodo
- Si tengo que usar una fecha en un **formato específico**, uso `CONVERT`
- Cuando tengo que lanzar consultas desde **código** *(en mi caso C# y .NET)* uso **consultas parametrizadas** para que sea la capa de acceso a datos la que haga la conversión

Answer (score 1):

Aunque ya esta respondida esta pregunta quiero hacer mi aporte.

A veces las consultas con fechas suelen ser complicadas ya que se depende del idioma, para evitar este tipo de inconvenientes es recomendable utilizar un formato estándar en la consulta, yo recomiendo utilizar el formato YYYYMMDD que se logra utilizando un convert de esta forma:

```
select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 112)
```

**tu consulta quedaría de esta manera:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM PR_11 
WHERE convert(nvarchar, FECHA_DESDE, 112) > '20140728' AND CODIGO='4891'
```

Ahora bien, parece tedioso convertir al formato YYYYMMDD las fechas pero el ahorro en dolor de cabeza es importante, llevo mas de 12 años utilizando este método y debo decir que jamás he tenido ningún inconveniente debido a la configuración regional.

Otro ejemplo suponiendo que tengo un stored procedure que recibe un datetime o smalldatetime, habría que convertir al formato antes dicho.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_devuelve_listado_fecha_mayor 
        @fecha datetime,
        @codigo int
as
SELECT * 
FROM PR_11 
WHERE       convert(nvarchar, FECHA_DESDE, 112) >  convert(nvarchar, @fecha, 112)
        AND CODIGO = @codigo
```

una úlima opción es convertir la fecha al formato YYYYMMDD desde la aplicación y enviar el string al stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_devuelve_listado_fecha_mayor 
        @fecha nvarchar(8),
        @codigo int
as
SELECT * 
FROM PR_11 
WHERE       convert(nvarchar, FECHA_DESDE, 112) >  @fecha
        AND CODIGO = @codigo
```

Espero que pueda ser de utilidad como me servido durante tanto tiempo.

**PD:  Por efectos de simplicidad se ha utilizado `Select *` POR FAVOR en consultas reales sólo utilizar los campos necesarios.**

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo mio tan sencillo como especificar la fecha de esta manera '2014-07-28' no hay que hacer converciones, se puede ahorrar tiempo y codigo de esta manera

Comment: Hola, si te fijas en mi respuesta, también mencioné esa posibilidad y como dices ahorras tiempo pero no es segura al 100%. Échale un vistazo a este artículo ["Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries"](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx)

Comment: Tienes razon, disculpa, y gracias por el articulo lo revisare ;)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes setear la fecha Como DMY

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SELECT * FROM PR_11 WHERE FECHA_DESDE > '28/07/2014' AND CODIGO='4891';
```